# Is it possible to make a sequence individual for set of properties values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Model is

```
public class Document
{
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public string Prop1 {get;set;}
public string Prop2 {get;set;}
public string Prop3 {get;set;}
public int DocumentVersion  {get;set;}
}
```

Using only ef core model builder like in this example

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("DocumentVersions");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .Property(o => o.DocumentVersion)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.DocumentVersions");
}
```

is it possible to configure autoincrement field (DocumentVersion) that individually iterates depending of values of Prop1, Prop2, Prop3? Every set of values of props should have its own sequence.

For example:

```
Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 DocumentVersion
1     1     1     1
1     1     1     2
1     2     1     1
1     2     3     1
1     1     1     3
1     2     1     2
```

1. Stored procedure solution for generating DocumentVersion is **not** suitable.
2. Pure C# solution for generating DocumentVersion is **not** suitable.

Comment: Maybe you need to rethink this. The document is the one and only entity. Changing its attributes (properties) doesn't change its *identity* and that's why it should always have a new version when one of the attributes changes. It seems to me that you want it to be another document (i.e. a new entity) when one of the attributes changes. If that is true you maybe should create a new document with this unique combination of attributes, having its own versioning.

Comment: (Continued) At any rate, to me it seems a big pain in the neck when someone asks for "version 5 of document X" and you have to ask "which, erm... version of version 5 of document X"?